# (Multi processing) Why the code written under "if __name__ == '__main__':" Without indentation runs several times, equal to num of cores, in PyCharm

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

This is my code:

```py
import multiprocessing
import time

def list_function_multiprocessing(setlist, function):
    from multiprocessing import Pool
    num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    pool = Pool(processes=num_cores-4)
    start = time.time()
    results_list = pool.starmap(function, setlist)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return results_list, time.time() - start


odKeyList = list((tGr, i[0], i[1], 5) for i in scaled_od_dic)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    res01, res01CTime = list_function_multiprocessing(odKeyList, kth_shortest_path)
    print(res01CTime)

print('het')
```

As you can see I have `print('het')` outside of the `if __name__ == '__main__':`. the result in python is:

[image: Result]

as you can see, the line `print('het')` has been executed 16 times which is equal to the number of cores engaged in process (20-4). I want to write a big chunk of code this part, and my concern is the other chunk is executed several times as well.

I would appreciate if anyone can help me.

I have tried writing the function out of the main script in a separate file. But it didn't work without `if __name__ == '__main__':` idiom in the main script. The only way that I could make it work was the time that I put `print('het')` under `if __name__ == '__main__':` idiom.

Comment: This is exactly how `multiprocessing` is documented to work.  *ALL* top-level executable code has to go inside that block; only definitions (data or functions) can go outside.

Comment: I just don't want the whole script to work with multiprocessing. I want to see if I can separate them. some blocks with multi-processing and some not.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what behaviour you do want from your code?

Comment: There are options that don't work this way (forking mode) but availability is OS-specific. If you want to support Windows, you're stuck with this -- and since you know about it, how is it still a problem?

Comment: `if __name__ == '__main__'` is not a dividing line; it's an ordinary `if` statement whose *body* is only executed if the condition is true. *Conventionally*, a script *ends* with this statement, but that is not required; additional code following the statement will be executed normally.